# How can I add a manifest (for UAC support) to my VB.NET application?

Tags: vb.net, windows, manifest, uac

How can I add and embed a manifest file in VB.NET, in order to add UAC support to my application?

Answer (score 7):

In VB.NET 2010, go to Project → My Project → Application→ View Windows Settings.

You'll see the default manifest. From here, you can change it as you desire.

For example, in this case, to require UAC elevation when the application launches, change:

```
requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"
```

to

```
requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a manifest specifying the privileges you require.

Choose *Project->Add New Item...*, and select *Application Manifest File*.

A sample manifest file will be created containing a `<requestedExecutionLevel>` entry and an explanation what to do with it.

This only works with Visual Studio 2008 (and probably later).

To add the manifest to 2005, [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2006/04/06/568563.aspx) might help. It looks rather complicated.

Comment: thanks, how can I embed it within the exe file? is there a command line for post build?

Comment: >>Choose Project->Add New Item..., and select Application Manifest File.

This is not existed in VB.net VS 2005

Comment: Sorry, the "Application Manifest File" template is not provided by default for vb.NET projects.