# Move file access to path is denied

Tags: vb.net, path

I'm using a code in VB.net to move my application from it's current path to `C:\file.exe` , the problem is:

When the app works under admin privileges it works, but when it works under normal user privileges , it doesn't; It says *`Access to path is denied`* . Although I know similar app which does the same function and works under standard user without the above problem .

The code:

```
Dim filepath As String = Application.ExecutablePath
Dim newfilepath As String = "C:\file.exe"
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    System.IO.File.Move(filepath, newfilepath)
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question. It's because of UAC settings new in vista and later MS OS

Comment: But the when I run the app , it doesn't show UAC windows ? can this be changed through the project settings ?

Comment: It says bad request .. btw : can I apply the above code without UAC permission ?

Comment: What says bad request? and if you want to use "C:\file.exe" you need UAC

Comment: the link you gave me , it says bad request when i open it . I know a similar application in Delphi , but it doesn't require UAC ?

Comment: new [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431948/how-to-add-uac-manifest-file-to-vb-net)

Comment: Sorry I don't know a lot about delphi, so I can't comment on that

Comment: if application.executable path resolves  -as it normally would - to somewhere within Program Files then you _will_ need admin permissions to do that (on Vista and later)