# VB 2013 - route add cmd elevated

Tags: vb.net

After a few days of googeling and trying i thought let met ask it my self. 
I am trying to make this happen: 
http://gyazo.com/5274568fcb55a0fe042936e375c0b424
The show current routes is working just fine, and displays the text i ask him to show.

But the route adding not so much let me show you the code :)

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim cmdThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf CmdAutomate2)
    cmdThread.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub CmdAutomate2()
    Dim myprocess As New Process
    Dim startInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd" 
    startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = False 
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = True 
    myprocess.StartInfo = startInfo
    myprocess.Start()
    Dim sR As System.IO.StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
    Dim sW As System.IO.StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput
    sW.WriteLine("route add" & textbox1.text & " " & textbox2.text) 
    sW.WriteLine("exit") 'exits command prompt window
    results = sR.ReadToEnd 'returns results of the command window
    sW.Close()
    sR.Close()
    Invoke(finished)
End Sub
```

Now i know you should use different pieces of code here mainly: 
startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
instead of: 
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False

But that gives me errors with the redirect (which i found to be confimed as not possible somewhere else in this forum)

Now i dont care for it to show the output i have the other button for it.
But i cannot seem to et this to work as i get different errors all the time like cannot reditect ot redirect not started with different combinations of code from all over the web,,

What am i missing here??

Comment: Are you running this as administrator (i.e. with UAC elevation)?

Comment: You could run the programm as admin with the right mouse button, but i rather do it in the code with something like " startInfo.Verb = "runas" " but it does give errors with putting in the command

Comment: I can't as I don't have the app, but are you doing that?

Comment: No i run VS studio as a normal user, and then press start which in turn builds the program as a normal user. which then needs to get elevated to admin which causes errors. but i can agree that right click run as admin would be easier. so thats a no.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add UAC manifest file to vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431948/how-to-add-uac-manifest-file-to-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to edit the route table for your PC, your app needs to run as administrator. you can add a [manifest to your application which declares that you require administrator privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1431948/50447), which should prompt as required.

Comment: Both of them were in the manifest removing the asinvoker did not change the outcome as i still would need admin rights

Comment: Yes, you must have admin rights to be able to change the route table. Adding the relevant setting to the manifest should do the right thing when executing, and prompt for admin privileges.