# Delete a single .txt file if exist in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

i have been trying to figure out how to delete a .txt file that constantly change name exept the first 4 ex: THISTEXT-123-45.txt where THISTEXT stays the same but -123-45 changes.

I have found a way to detect it, but i don't know how to delete it.

```
Dim paths() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "THISTEXT*.txt")
If paths.Length > 0 Then
```

Anyone knows the command line to delete that special .txt file?
I am using Visual Basic on visual studio 2013 framework 3.5.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer about deleting a name changing file, only the first 4 letter are the same for all file.

Comment: @GUNNER I think what's confusing everybody is that even though your example shows `THISTEXT*.txt`, you keep referring to a singular file (e.g. "that file" in comments below). Is there only one and you want to delete it? Or, are there many and you want to delete them all? Or, are there many and you want to delete just a specific one? Please clarify.

Comment: @GUNNER *Now* it works, please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the MSDN page on [`GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx), you will realize that you have the file name and path in your paths array. You can then iterate through the array deleting your matches.

```
Dim x as Integer
Dim paths() as String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "THISTEXT*.txt")
If paths.Length > 0 Then
    For x = 0 to paths.Length -1
        IO.File.Delete(paths(x))
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Do you actually need to check `paths.Length > 0` first?

Comment: @Jason No it is not necessary, it will just fall through. I just have always got in the habit of checking the bounds of my arrays before using them.

Comment: Hello Mark Hall, When i execute your code, it gives me this error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll , showing me this part of the code :`IO.File.Delete(paths(x))`

Comment: You must not have permission to delete the files in the root directory, that is what that error is telling you, I tested it in a subdirectory that I had privileges to.

Comment: @Mark Hall Is there any way to give permission via coding? Or is it impossible to remove a file from the C:\ with a program?

Comment: Try running your program as an administrator

Comment: Sir, i love you! problem resolved. thank you Mark Hall! Oh and, is there a way to make the program run as admin automatically, without the need to enable it manually?

Comment: @GUNNER You will need to look into using an [application manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374191(v=vs.85).aspx) to request elevation.  also see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431948/how-to-add-uac-manifest-file-to-vb-net/1431981#1431981)

Comment: Thanks found it!!  `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` its all good now. have a nice day!

Answer (score 5):

Use the Delete method of System.IO.

Assuming you have write access to C:\

```
Dim FileDelete As String

FileDelete = "C:\testDelete.txt"

 If System.IO.File.Exists( FileDelete ) = True Then
   System.IO.File.Delete( FileDelete )
   MsgBox("File Deleted")
End If
```

> Deleting a file is quite simple - but dangerous! So be very careful when you're trying out this code.

**Edit**
To delete all file use *(asterisk) followed with the file extension

example `C:\*.txt"`

For multiple files

```
Dim FileDelete As String

FileDelete = "C:\"

For Each FileDelete  As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(FileDelete & "THISTEXT*.txt")
    File.Delete(FileDelete)
Next
```

Comment: Hello! thanks for the quick answer, but once i try to declare the "C:\", "THISTEXT*.txt" it dosnt work, C:\ works, but once i put the "," the rest of the text stay black with a blue line under saying (identifier expected)              `Dim fyle As String = "C:\","THISTEXT*.txt"`

Comment: @GUNNER Use the path and filename as one, don't use them separately.

Comment: Error checking and exception handling are important but trying to teach them as well as a method to delete a file all in one shot might be a bit overwhelming for a new programmer. I think this answer does a fine job of answering the specific question. The asker will have plenty of opportunity to learn proper error handling techniques and such later, this is not the only chance to teach them.

Comment: @JasonC I was talking about Omar, not the OP of the question. The code Omar initially provided was, there's not really any other way to say this, shocking for an answer. Sure, it pushed all the right buttons, but it did not use proper functionality of VB.NET, it was basically pseudocode.

Comment: Guys, i see alot of explaination about how to delete a file with the same name. but the real question here is how to delete a file that NEVER have the same name.( so FileToDelete = "C:\testDelete.txt" ) is invalid for me. since it will never be testdelete.txt since it changes, only the first 4 letter are the same.

Comment: @GUNNER I'm confused, so why not replace the file variable with yours? Please see my own answer to be sure.

Comment: @Omar What if the OP does *not* have access to `C:\`, what do they do then (other than the program crashing, of cause)?. As of now, this does not answer the question.

Comment: A software create a .txt for every update and it create a really long and complete .txt name the only thing that never changes are the first 4 letter. all i need is to press a button to remove that file automatically. i could remove it manually but id prefer a program to remove all those.  `Dim paths() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "THISTEXT*.txt")
If paths.Length > 0 Then` line of code detect the file, but i don't know any command to delete that file with a unknown full name.

Comment: @Omar You *still* haven't met the OP's requirement. They need specific files deleted, not the whole folder.

Answer (score 1):

To build on the feedback you provided to [Omar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4539709/omar) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30584901/2422013), it appears that your file path and file name are separate.

You cannot provide them separated by a comma, as commas denote separate parameters passed to a subroutine or function.

To fix this, you need to concatenate them, for example:

```
Dim fileName As String = "foo.txt"
Dim filePath As String = "C:\"

Dim FileToDelete As String = fileName + filePath
```

To delete a single `.*txt` file if it exists:

```
If (deleteFile("C:\")) Then 
    MsgBox("File deletion successful")
Else
        MsgBox("File couldn't be deleted with the following error: " + exception)
End If
```

alternatively with concatenation:

```
If (deleteFile("C:\") Then
    MsgBox("File deletion successful")
Else
        MsgBox("File couldn't be deleted with the following error: " + exception)
End If
```

---

```
Dim exception As String 'Place this at the beginning of your app's class.

    Dim path As String = "C:\"
    If (deleteFile(path)) Then
        MsgBox("File deletion successful")
    Else
        MsgBox("File couldn't be deleted with the following error: " + exception)
    End If

Private Function deleteFile(ByVal dir) As Boolean
    Dim fileToRemove As String
    Try
        Dim paths() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "THISTEXT*.txt")
        For i As Integer = 0 To paths.Length
            fileToRemove = paths(i).ToString
            System.IO.File.Delete(fileToRemove)
            If (Not System.IO.File.Exists(fileToRemove)) Then
                Return True
            Else
                exception = "Unknown error."
                Return False
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        exception = ex.Message
        Return False
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

The above function checks if the file exists, if it does it tries to delete it. If the file cannot be deleted, or an error occurs (which is handled), the Function returns `False`.

Comment: What if you want to present the error in a manner besides that message box, or reuse this code in multiple contexts that have their own ways to present an error?

Comment: @JasonC That's a simple matter that people using the code can adapt to. It'd be as simple as storing the error within a variable, or calling another subroutine to act on the error.

Comment: I suppose "error handling is a simple matter that people using the code can adapt to" would have been a good response to the comments on the other answer, too! Anyways, good improvement. Now, what if you want to display a more informative error depending on whether the file didn't exist vs. could not be deleted?

Comment: @JasonC Was thinking of adding that, will do so now.

Comment: Interesting approach. What if you want to do this from multiple threads? Do you recommend using a higher-scoped variable to store an error message rather than throwing exceptions? Is this the best technique? Will this potentially get messy in more complex applications?

Comment: @JasonC Yes, I recommend a global, since it'll save memory, but however a delegate must be created in order to access the variable. I won't flatter myself by stating that this is the best technique since there's likely other techniques out there that are better.

Comment: I see, although in my opinion if the goal is to demonstrate proper error handling to a new programmer, extra care should be taken to present the best technique (go big or go home, as they say), no? Will the amount of memory it saves be significant compared to the amount of memory typically available on platforms this code is likely to run on? Exactly how much less memory does it use? Perhaps it is better to leave the error handling lesson out for now if it cannot be taught completely?

Comment: @JasonC I haven't measured it, but I'd say the amount of memory saved between platforms would be minimal.

Comment: Well that does not seem to be compelling. But, on the other hand, the OP will also likely learn effective use of higher-scoped variables later on as well, so I suppose it works out. This code would probably be a lot easier to modify and maintain and have a simpler structure if exceptions were used instead, but it is not complex code anyways. Hopefully the OP uses discretion in the mean time.

Comment: Nice update. Do you recommend leaving `dir` as a parameter but hardcoding "THISTEXT*.txt" as opposed to parameterizing both? Also, this code fails as soon as one error is encountered. Would you recommend that over trying to delete as many as possible, or even attempting to rollback and make *no* changes on an error?

Comment: @JasonC If the user wishes to implement a rollback function, they are free to do so, but however that's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
    For Each path As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\", "THISTEXT*.txt")
        Try
            System.IO.File.Delete(path)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(path, "Unable to Delete File")
        End Try
    Next
```

Comment: now i see some results, but i get the message box saying it cannot delete the .txt though... gah this sucks